# Wrong number of arguments - resque

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque

I have a job create_site_map.rb like below:

```
class CreateSiteMap
  @queue = :create_site_map
  def self.perform(slct_common_path, http_host, site_id)
  end
end
```

And a rake file:

```
require "resque/tasks"
require "resque/scheduler/tasks"

namespace :create_site_map do
  desc "Create site map"

  task create_site_map: :environment do
    Resque.enqueue CreateSiteMap, 0, "a", 1071
  end
end
```

When I run resque in Termial :

```
Resque.enqueue_to(:high, CreateSiteMap, 0, "abc", 1071)
```

or:

```
Resque.enqueue(CreateSiteMap)
```

it's show error like this: `wrong number of arguments (given 0, expected 3)`
pls help me
How can I pass arguments in resque?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By looking at the code here

https://github.com/resque/resque/blob/master/lib/resque.rb#L386

It seems like, if you are using `enqueue`, you should pass the class name and the parameters

```
# https://github.com/resque/resque/blob/master/lib/resque.rb#L402
def enqueue(klass, *args)
  enqueue_to(queue_from_class(klass), klass, *args)
end
```

or if you are using `enqueue_to`,

- queue -> queue name as string
- klass -> class
- *args -> arguments

```
# https://github.com/resque/resque/blob/master/lib/resque.rb#L415
def enqueue_to(queue, klass, *args)
```

So, in your case,

```
# using enqueue 
Resque.enqueue(CreateSiteMap, 0, "abc", 1071)
```

```
# using enqueue_to
Resque.enqueue_to('high', CreateSiteMap, 0, "abc", 1071)
```

NOTE: the queue in enqueue_to is a string

Answer (score 0):

I can't seem to reproduce this. I'm trying with a file called `test.rb` with the following contents:

```
require 'resque'
Resque.logger.level = Logger::DEBUG

class CreateSiteMap
  @queue = :create_site_map
  def self.perform(slct_common_path, http_host, site_id)
    puts http_host
  end
end

Resque.enqueue_to(:high, CreateSiteMap, 0, "abc", 1071)

# Now perform the job
klass, args = Resque.reserve(:high)
klass.perform(*args)
```

And when running this with

```
$ ruby test.rb
```

It outputs `abc` as expected.

Comment: I try with your suggest but it's not working :(
I updated my post, pls read again and help me :(